# Setting a cookie on first page load

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie in wordpress that comes from $_GET so I've put this in the bottom of my theme's functions.php:

```
function set_name_cookie() {
    if (isset($_GET['kw'])) {
        setcookie('kw',$_GET['kw'], time()+3600*24, '/','.website.com',false);   
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_name_cookie');
```

I can see cookies as they're set in Firefox. This cookie is not set when I first load the page, but if I reload the page it is.

Many people have a similar issue where cookie is not set until after the page is loaded so they can't use $_COOKIE['kw'] dynamically in the same page as it's set, but that's not my issue, it's just not setting, when I go to the next page, the $_COOKIE is still empty unless I reload that first page (with the ?kw=XXX in the URL). What could cause that behavior? Is this how it's supposed to work?

EDIT - When I go to mysite.com/test.php?kw=123 which looks like this:

```
<?
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['kw'])) {
    setcookie('kw',$_GET['kw'], time()+3600*24,'/',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],false);   
}
?>
<html>
    <a href="test2.php">check cookie</a>
</html>
```

And then click on the link to test2.php, which looks like this:

```
session_start();
echo 'cookie:'.print_r($_COOKIE);
exit;
```

I don't see a cookie it's just empty array. If I go back in my browser to test.php and then click through again, I can see it. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: try setting the cookie with javascript.

Comment: How do I read it in PHP on the 2nd page though? Output is Array ( ) cookie:1

Comment: same as how you read it with your previous PHP code, or use Pure javascript http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: not sure why you are using session?

Comment: Sorry session was from something else I'd tried, I'll remove.

Comment: session could be the reason why youre having issue,

Comment: Without session_start(), I can't get it to show the cookie at all. It's like it can't read the kw cookie unless there is also a PHPSESSID cookie present (the PHPSESSID cookie also only shows up on page reload).

Comment: its seems like you are doing something wrong, try making your cookie work first without session http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp, or just use javascript to read/write/edit/delete cookie

Comment: I was able to get it to work in javascript, but I need to be able to get the cookie on the server side. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Cookies cannot be "server side', yet if set properly, you should be able to read the Cookie via PHP using the `$_COOKIE['kw']` variable. What code are you using currently?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm having exactly the same issue as you. Cookie isn't set on the first page load, but if I reload the page, it is. Did you ever find a solution?